# No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-support-library

Now I know that this question has been asked many times but the solution that has always been proposed has not worked for me. It has been said that the minimum SDK version has to be greater than 10 in order for showAsAction to be used. In my manifest file, I have set my minimum sdk at 17 and my target sdk at 17. What else could be causing this error? Here is my menu's XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Text2Morse="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/SettingsID"
    Text2Morse:showAsAction="ifroom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_gearl"
    android:title="@string/MySetting">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ReadMeID"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_readmel"
    android:title="@string/Read_me">
</item>
```

Could it be that the support library is not properly included on the build path? To include the support library on the build path I was following the steps posted on the android development website:[Support Library SetUp](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

I got through the first part alright but when I get down part that says "Add the library to your application project" things don't work. 
[Directions](http://i39.tinypic.com/2873uwk.png)

For example, on step 2 for this portion of the directions it says "In the Library pane, click Add". I do not know what program they are using but I am using eclipse. **There is no add button in the Library tab for me. There is only add jars, add external jars, add variable, add library, add class folder, add external class folder.** There is an add button in the Projects tab but this is not the Library tab. I have even experimented by assuming that the directions really mean to refer to the project tab and following the steps from there. I add the Support Library project folder but I still see the same error.

All I want is for some of my menu items to show up on the action bar. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: use this `android:showAsAction="ifroom"`

Comment: I have also tried this and I am still seeing the same error

Answer (score 0):

I spent forever trying to make this work in the XML, and never could.  I suspect a problem with build path and the support libraries.

I was able to make this work by setting the flag in Java instead:

```
menu.add(0, MENU_FULLSCREEN, 0, "Fullscreen").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_fullscreen).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

Comment: *spent forever* was nice haha